# Reference Error: Text Encoder is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

I am trying to use mongoose with my code. But as soon as I try to add mongoose by adding this piece of code

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
```

I get this error:

```
const utf8Encoder = new TextEncoder();
                    ^

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
```

Also I'm using mongodb in Ubuntu 20.04, someone told me to reinstall mongo to no use

Comment: It has nothing to do with MongoDB or mongoose. What's your node version? It should be v12 or more.

Comment: i checked the node version is  v16.9.1, but the nodejs version is v10.19.0 I can't find a way to update nodejs version.

Comment: To check your version please run **node -v** command. If you want to update it, try using nvm.

Comment: update: I reinstalled the whole package using nodesource distribution it's working.

Answer (score 0):

i downloaded the latest version of node js but whenever i checked it on hyper terminal with command of node --version it shows me version 10 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlkBX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dqx2.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm pretty sure that your answer actually does not answer anything that OP asked. And he stated at comments that he solved by reinstalling the whole package using nodesource distribution.